# Why is django TestCase not connecting to test database?

Tags: django, django-testing

1
I am writing a Django test inheriting from django.test.TestCase. Everywhere, in the docs, it says a test db will be automatically created. Here I am using the very standard approach but the test_get_opportunity  class method is using my production db. Even tough a test db is created the objects.create doesnot populate it with data and the datas are fetched from my production db
Please see my code bellow.

```
from django.test import TestCase
import request
from core.models import Opportunity

class OpportunityViewTest(TestCase):
    def test_get_opportunity(self):
        # Create a test opportunity
        opportunity = Opportunity.objects.create(name='TestOpportunity', created_by='postgres')

        print(opportunity.id)
        # Set up the request
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/pure-protect/opportunity/"
        data = {'opportunity_id': opportunity.id}

        response = requests.get(url, data)

        print(response.json())

        # Assert the response
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(response.json()['status'], 'success')
```

I have used --keepdb to verify id the data is updated in the table but its not updated
When i hard code the opportunity_id in request. I see the datas are fetched from production db
What do I do wrong and what has to be done so a test db is  used for the test?